# How to properly rig a watch to an arm

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

So in order to fix the wrist-twisting, I use bendy bone the twist the wrist erea (pic1). But this make the watch also twist too(pic2)
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 1].

So is there a way to properly rig the watch or better way to rig the arm?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Are you sure it's a rigid-body-simulation problem?

I guess what you want is to deform the bracelet but not the watch. To do so you could use **Make Vertex Parent**. In my screenshot I just kept the watch and its bracelet but of course the bracelet is supposed to be part of the same mesh as the character and his arm.

- Make the watch a different object from the bracelet. Now select the watch, then the bracelet and go in *Edit* mode.

[image]

- Select 3 bracelet vertices, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*

[image]

- Now when you deform the arm (and therefore the bracelet) the watch follow but doesn't deform.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easiest way is to use a 'child of' or 'copy transform' constraint to the watch and the forearm bone as its target.

Comment: +1, this is a really good constraint for things like this, also it's great because you can animate the influence to change whether or not it's  parented.